# How can I loop a data matrix in R?

Tags: r, loops, matrix, dataframe

I am trying to loop a data matrix for each separate ID tag, “1”, “2” and “3” (see my data at the bottom). Ultimately I am doing this to transform the X and Y coordinates into a timeseries with the ts() function, but first i need to build a loop into the function that returns a timeseries for each separate ID. The looping itself works perfectly fine when I use the following code for a dataframe:

`for(i in 1:3){
    print(na.omit(xyframe[ID==i,]))
    }`

Returning the following output:

```
 Timestamp X Y ID  
 1. 0 -34.012 3.406 1  
 2. 100 -33.995 3.415 1  
 3. 200 -33.994 3.427 1

 Timestamp       X     Y ID  
 4.          0 -34.093 3.476 2  
 5.        100 -34.145 3.492 2  
 6.        200 -34.195 3.506 2  

   Timestamp       X     Y ID  
 7.         0 -34.289 3.522 3  
 8.       100 -34.300 3.520 3  
 9.       200 -34.303 3.517 3
```

Yet, when I want to produce a loop in a matrix with the same code:

`for(i in 1:3){
    print(na.omit(xymatrix[ID==i,])
    }`

It returns the following error:

```
Error in print(na.omit(xymatrix[ID == i, ]) : 
  (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

Why does it not work to loop the ID through a matrix while it does work for the dataframe and how would I be able to fix it? 
Furthermore did I read that looping requires much more computational strength then doing the same thing vector based, would there be a way to do this vector based?

***The data (simplification of the real data):***

```
 Timestamp X Y ID  
 1.   0 -34.012 3.406 1  
 2. 100 -33.995 3.415 1  
 3. 200 -33.994 3.427 1  
 4.   0 -34.093 3.476 2  
 5. 100 -34.145 3.492 2  
 6. 200 -34.195 3.506 2  
 7.   0 -34.289 3.522 3  
 8. 100 -34.300 3.520 3  
 9. 200 -34.303 3.517 3
```

Comment: Have you declared a variable named `ID` elsewhere?  Your code snippet isn't using the ID column from the data frame or the matrix, but another variable called ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `xymatrix[ID==i,]` doesn't work for matrix. Try this way:

```
for(i in 1:3){ print(na.omit(xymatrix[xymatrix[,'ID'] == i,])) }
```

Comment: Let's clarify: `xymatrix[ID == i,]` would not work with data.frames either. Unless the OP had a `ID` variable in his environment, which is obviously the case from 1) not getting an error with the data.frame and 2) not getting the right error message (`object 'ID' not found`) when using a matrix. The only reason the OP's code errored out is because his matrix and `ID` variable have non-compatible dimensions.

Comment: That's right, I was thinking in data$variable calling. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want to *apply* a function to a data frame, *split* by some factor, then you should be using one of the `apply` family of functions in combination with `split`.

Here's some reproducible sample data.

```
n <- 20  
some_data <- data.frame(
  x = sample(c(1:5, NA), n, replace= TRUE), 
  y = sample(c(letters[1:5], NA), n, replace= TRUE),
  id = gl(3, 1, length = n)
)
```

If you want to print out the rows with no missing values, split by each ID level, then you want something like this.

```
lapply(split(some_data, some_data$grp), na.omit)
```

or more concisely using the `plyr` package.

```
library(plyr)
dlply(some_data, .(grp), na.omit)
```

Both methods return output like this

```
# $`1`
   # x y grp
# 1  2 d   1
# 4  3 e   1
# 7  3 c   1
# 10 4 a   1
# 13 2 e   1
# 16 3 a   1
# 19 1 d   1

# $`2`
  # x y grp
# 2 1 e   2
# 5 3 e   2
# 8 3 b   2

# $`3`
   # x y grp
# 6  3 c   3
# 9  5 a   3
# 12 2 c   3
# 15 2 d   3
# 18 4 a   3
```

Comment: For each answer that was helpful to you, click the up arrow next to the score on the left to upvote it.

Comment: Very elucidating and helpful, yet, these methods only work for dataframes and not matrices, why is that and how can the same methods be applied for matrices? thank you very much!

Comment: You can apply functions rowwise to data frame with `apply(data, 1, your_function)`.

Comment: `split` doesn't support matrices because that's a very unusual thing to want to split up.  Convert to your matrix to be a data frame with `as.data.frame`.